# Path not showing in d3.js topoJson graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, topojson

I am trying to draw a map using topoJson so I followed this example

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4122298

but I am not getting anything drawn.

here's what i wrote

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: .5px;
}

path:hover {
  fill: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var path = d3.geo.path();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

  d3.json("tunisia.json", function(error, topology) {

  console.log(topology);

  svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.governorates).features)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", path);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

After some debugging it turns out that the path in my case is added as follows:

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
<path></path>
<path></path>
</svg>
```

whereas it should normally be like this:

```
<svg width="960" height="500">
 <path d="M183.85631949544694,17.16574961388676L184.64695256075555,18.261986556132797L184.24437929962187,21.436416964644536L184.9109502450185,22.72190753660925L183.42733139583214,23.600229178621248L181.43637647772152,23.38526266060535L162.4858998398068,18.04698631290296L162.95134674943927,16.322885588815097L161.24381018256219,15.20848145955324L160.04585728433227,11.701769628478132L161.0879861841512,10.793553936506555L172.9773901748378,14.256236175137701Z"></path>
</svg>
```

here is the data I am using: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mtimet/tnacmaps/master/topojson/tunisia.json

could you please check what I am doing wrong

Comment: Could you post a sample of your TopoJSON?  It could be incorrectly formatted.

Comment: yes, i've just done that

Comment: Nothing is jumping out at me.  I do see that there are non-ASCII characters in your TopoJSON.  Perhaps that is causing the problem?

Comment: I'm not experienced enough with topoJSON to tell you the exact issue, but I punched the data into [here](http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-geo-renderer.html), and it seemed to think it wasn't a topoJSON file. Seems like it's probably the data format.

Comment: @MikePrecup I tried the link u give http://techslides.com/demos/d3/d3-geo-renderer.html with the data that is already working in the example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4122298 but It's giving also the message 'This file does not seem to be topojson or geojson.'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no problem with your json file.

The issue you are having is that you are not defining a projection for your [`d3.geo.path()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path) which means it falls back to the default. According to the documentation linked above:

> `#d3.geo.path()`
>
> Creates a new geographic path generator with the default settings: the [albersUsa](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#wiki-albersUsa) projection and a point radius of 4.5 pixels.

Your geo data is for a map of Tunisia, so an albersUsa projection won't contain any of the coordinates in your dataset. That is why the path data is empty in your output.

To fix this, you need to define a projection. You can do this when you load your data, and you can use `d3.geo.bounds()`, passing in your `featureCollection` to find the geographic boundaries of your data.

```
var featureCollection = topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.governorates);
var bounds = d3.geo.bounds(featureCollection);
```

Then from these boundaries, you can calculate the center of your featureCollection:

```
var centerX = d3.sum(bounds, function(d) {return d[0];}) / 2,
    centerY = d3.sum(bounds, function(d) {return d[1];}) / 2;
```

Then you can use this to center your projection. For example, if you're using a mercator projection, you could do the following:

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(3000)
  .center([centerX, centerY]);
```

The choice of a scale of 3000 is arbitrary, it just seemed to work well in this case, tweak it to whatever works for you.

Finally, you need to set the `.projection()` of your `path` to the projection you made, before actually creating the svg paths.

```
path.projection(projection);

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(featureCollection.features)
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("d", path);
```

[**HERE**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jVbClD4cQCbdPpxGFlYj?p=preview) is a working example using your data.